# Is there a way to collect a map using "groupingBy" for MULTIPLE elements within a nested structure?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, grouping

First, a bit of context code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.DoubleAdder;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Scratch {

  static enum Id {A, B, C}
  static class IdWrapper {
    private final Id id;
    public IdWrapper(Id id) {this.id = id;}
    Id getId() { return id; }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Object> v1 = new HashMap<>();
    v1.put("parents", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new IdWrapper(Id.A), new IdWrapper(Id.B))));
    v1.put("size", 1d);

    Map<String, Object> v2 = new HashMap<>();
    v2.put("parents", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new IdWrapper(Id.B), new IdWrapper(Id.C))));
    v2.put("size", 2d);

    Map<String, Map<String, Object>> allVs = new HashMap<>();
    allVs.put("v1", v1);
    allVs.put("v2", v2);
```

The above represents the data structure I am dealing with. I have an outer map (key type is irrelevant), that contains inner "property maps" as values. These inner maps use strings to lookup different kind of data.

In the case I am working on, each v1, v2,... represents a "disk". Each disk has a specific size, but can have multiple parents.

Now I need to sum up the sizes *per* parent Id as `Map<Id, Double>`. 
For the above example, that map would be `{B=3.0, A=1.0, C=2.0}`.

The following code gives the expected result:

```
    HashMap<Id, DoubleAdder> adders = new HashMap<>();
    allVs.values().forEach(m -> {
        double size = (Double) m.get("size");
        Set<IdWrapper> wrappedIds = (Set<IdWrapper>) m.get("parents");
        wrappedIds.forEach(w -> adders.computeIfAbsent(w.getId(), a -> new DoubleAdder()).add(size));
    });

    System.out.println(adders.keySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), key -> adders.get(key).doubleValue())));
```

But the code feels pretty clunky (like the fact that I need a second map for adding up the sizes).

I have a similar case, where there is always exactly one parent, and that can easily be solved using

```
collect(Collectors.groupingBy(...), Collectors.summingDouble(...);
```

But I am lost for the "multiple" parents case.

So, question: can the above transformation to compute the required `Map<Id, Double>` be rewritten using `groupingBy()`?

And just for the record: the above is just a mcve for the problem I need an answer for. I understand that the "data layout" might look strange. In reality, we actually have distinct classes representing these "disks" for example. But our "framework" also allows for accessing the properties of any object within the database using such IDs and property names. And sometimes, when you have performance issues, then fetching data in such a "raw property map" way is orders of magnitude faster compared to accessing the true "disk" objects themselves. In other words: I can't change anything about the context. My question is solely about rewriting that computation.

( I am constrained to Java8 and "standard" Java libraries, but *additional* answers for newer versions Java or nice non-standard ways of solving this will be appreciated, too )

Comment: *In the case I am working on, each v1, v2,... represents a "disk"* then create a Disk class with two typed properties instead of using a Map.

Comment: @JBNizet See my updates. The above is just an example, in reality, things are more complicated. And in reality, there is a good reason to use the above map approach (50 ms for a *full* lookup compared to 3 seconds ... and that is a small configuration)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a single stream pipeline solution:

```
Map<Id,Double> sums = allVs.values ()
                           .stream () 
                           .flatMap (m -> ((Set<IdWrapper>)m.get ("parents")).stream ()
                                                                             .map (i -> new SimpleEntry<Id,Double>(i.getId(),(Double)m.get ("size"))))
                           .collect (Collectors.groupingBy (Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                            Collectors.summingDouble (Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

Output:

```
{B=3.0, A=1.0, C=2.0}
```

The idea is to convert each inner `Map` to a `Stream` of entries where the key is an `Id` (of the "parents" `Set`) and the value is the corresponding "size".

Then it's easy to group the `Stream` into the desired output.

Comment: I had that idea as well, but couldn't see how to get there!

Comment: For larger data sets, it might be worth doing the `(Double)m.get ("size")` only once before streaming over `(Set<IdWrapper>)m.get ("parents")` instead of repeating it for every element.

Comment: @Holger that seems like a small optimization, given these inner `Map`s only have 2 keys. If the actual `Map`s are larger, it might be helpful, though not much (since `get` has constant expected time anyway).

Comment: The inner objects are `Set`s, not `Map`s, but yes, I already said “for larger data sets”. The operation has constant time, still hashing is not necessarily cheap (the type cast is not so much a problem) and it’s multiplied with the number of set elements.

Comment: @Holger I was referring to the inner `Map<String, Object>`, not to the `Set<IdWrapper>`s within those `Map`s.

Comment: But you’re iterating over the `Set<IdWrapper>` in the inner stream, so the number of elements in that set matters. Whether you have larger maps, is irrelevant, as you’re still doing only two lookups (if you move the second lookup out of the inner stream) and, as you said, each lookup is expected to run in constant time. But currently, you’re repeating the second lookup for every element of the `Set`.